# CKEditor not displaying in old Internet Explorer versions

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I've installed CKEditor on my website and it works fine in recent browsers, but it doesn't get displayed in Internet Explorer 6 and 7. After searching, I found the following on the CKEditor website:

```
Even the old Internet Explorer 6 is compatible with.
```

Source: http://cksource.com/ckeditor

I didn't change anything to the editor. I just included the Javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./includes/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

And when I want to display the editor, I use:

```
<label for="text">Text</label><br />
<textarea id="text" name="text" rows="3" cols="50">some text here</textarea><br />
<script type="text/javascript">
  CKEDITOR.replace('text');
</script>
```

Is it possible to get the editor to work in IE6/7?

Thanks

Comment: Do the examples on the CK website still run in IE6/7?  If so then it's a problem with your markup.  Could be something else on the page or in your CSS that is causing the editor not to display.  The odd position:relative in CSS somewhere can cause merry hell in these browsers.  I would advise starting from a simple page and building up to your target page to see what breaks it.

Comment: It seems the examples on the website indeed work fine, so I guess I'll have to start debugging the CSS. I really hate IE6 lol. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in IE6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues with CK Editor in IE 7 and it ended up being something in the actual HTML that was causing the problem.

If you are simply using 'some text here' in your example this is unlikely, but you may have filtered out the real content for security purposes?

When you say 'it doesn't get displayed' do you mean the whole CK Editor textarea, or do you get the menu's come up but with no content?

Before I figured out my problem, I had CK editor in a fairly advanced system full of other CSS / JS stuff, so I just made a copy of the whole project, then stripped things back bit by bit until I was left with as little code as possible where the problem persisted, makes it much easier to debug then :) good luck!